# Can my friend legally drive my car in Canada?

Tags: canada, automobiles, insurance, identity-cards

I am currently in Michigan, I have auto coverage with Progressive, and I'm planning on taking a trip to Toronto with a friend.

My insurance agent tells me that they need to issue me a Canadian ID card in case I get pulled over, but this card only has my name in it.  Is it legal for my friend to drive my car in Canada if I don't have a Canadian ID card for him?  (I would also be in the car, but I was hoping we could take turns driving.)  What could go wrong?  For example, what would happen if my friend is pulled over in Canada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a Canadian Interprovincial Insurance Card, documenting that you have at least $200,000 Cdn worth of third party liability insurance (all-inclusive).  The card will be in the name of the insured owner only.  Just as with your standard US insurance, any driver with your permission and a valid license will also be insured while operating the vehicle.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to guess that the "Canadian Interprovincial Insurance Card" is the "Canadian ID card" that my insurance agent says he is giving me.

Comment: @nukeguy It sure sounds like it is.